Documenting MySQL queries in Markdown
I'm very new to the field. I'm working on a SQL project which have lots of queries and I want to share my results on github via markdown report. I'am facing a problem copying the results of my queries from MySQL Workbench to markdown.
Example of MySQL query:
Select *  From subscriptions s join plans p On s.plan_id = p.plan_id
a picture from mysql workbench
I tried to copy them as text then pasting them to markdown but it does not work. How can I do it? Knowing that I don't want to share them as images. Thank you.

Make sure to right-click on the result grid and copy rows with headers.
Paste it in your .md file on GitHub and preview it.
If it still does not look the way you want it to look, you need to edit it to this format manually.
| Column 1  | Column 2  | Column 3  |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| Value 1   | Value 2   | Value 3   |
| Value 4   | Value 5   | Value 6   |


It does not look like that when I copy it, and it is soo mixed that can not be edited manually.

did you follow this?: "right-click on the result grid and copy rows with headers"

I tried to do it but on Mysql Workbench there so such choice. I have choieces like: Copy row, copy row (with names), copy row (unquoted), copy row (with names, unquoted) and so on.

Then it might be best to just export your table into a csv file and convert it to Markdown from there. Try this website convertcsv.com

Copying it directly cannot persist the table format, but you can export the result to csv, then convert it to markdown table using https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-markdown.htm
Example
For example, I have this csv file
Desk,Commodity,Trader Name,Trader Email,Quantity
D-1124,Soybean Meal,Edward Copeland,wum@ro.kr,"84,524"
D-9293,Milk,Fanny Glover,govogowod@wocbuir.do,"93,459"
D-2868,Cotton No.2,Barry Barton,luezcuv@ez.mo,"36,548"
D-9774,Corn,Ryan Sullivan,gebbah@hearde.fo,"63,188"

Then I paste it into the text field inside the web

You can also just input the file directly.
Then it will show the converted csv to markdown.

|Desk  |Commodity   |Trader Name    |Trader Email        |Quantity|
|------|------------|---------------|--------------------|--------|
|D-1124|Soybean Meal|Edward Copeland|wum@ro.kr           |84,524  |
|D-9293|Milk        |Fanny Glover   |govogowod@wocbuir.do|93,459  |
|D-2868|Cotton No.2 |Barry Barton   |luezcuv@ez.mo       |36,548  |
|D-9774|Corn        |Ryan Sullivan  |gebbah@hearde.fo    |63,188  |

Then you can use it on your markdown files.
